Total distance walked with buddy pokemon doesn't match evolution distance
To evolve my Pawmo, I need to walk 25 km with him. According to the "Total Activities" stats, we've walked together 8.6 km. According to the "Evolve" stats further down, we've only walked 7.5/25km.

Why is there such a discrepancy? The evolution requirement has always existed, so it's not like I could've walked with my buddy some distance before the requirement was added. Every km I've walked should have counted towards the evolution requirement, but it appears I've been short-changed a whole kilometer. What's going on?
This probably isn't some sort of delay/lag because I assigned Pawmo as my buddy at the end of a hike two days ago, and haven't fed him candies/activated him since -- so I had one total walking session with him that should account for all of the distance travelled.

I believe "Walk together" was intended to count only when your buddy is also activated on the map, while "Walk X km with your buddy" counts when that pokemon is simply your designated buddy. If so, they are different counters and should have different values. However, implementation could be different than intended.

"Walk together" counts distance while they are your buddy, whether or not they're on the map.
"Walk with your buddy" only counts distance when the buddy is on the map walking with you.
I may not remember correctly as it's been a few years, but Adventure Sync may not count as "with your buddy" as they're not visible.

If that were the case, then I'd expect the difference between the two to grow as "walk together" increases (whether they're on the map or not) and adventure together does not. But instead it remains at exactly 1km difference -- now we're at 9.7 total vs 8.7 adventure.

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yeah, I've had oddities like that too, but IIRC it's when I fed the buddy and they're on the map, and then travel too fast for them to keep up so they end up teleporting. With the buddy not on the map IDK how this would occur, but it is likely a bug.
